# rewrite ?id= URL to a random string

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I current have a url structure that looks like:

`www.myapp.com/post.php?id=234`

I would like to have:

`www.myapp.com/82734bnh2`

So, essentially, I'd like to have a random string for each post, unsure of how I would link this to the DB though. I have done some reading and assume that a mod_rewrite of some sort is what is needed. What can I try next?

Comment: You would have to store a `slug` and then in your router component have the route using it to retrieve your post. Hard to help more without more information...

Comment: Hi. Yep - so for every insert, I created a randomid using uniqid() and then build the URL around that. Next step is to use mod_rewrite to remove the ?= part of the URL. Thanks for your help!